# laravel can't create function inside the app/http/controller/productController.php

Tags: php, laravel

Look at the image. I create changeName function inside the controller but it does not work.

My route :

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

why?

I tried to check all the syntax and it is correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might that your view is missed

Comment: @Java Script what error you got?

Comment: Can you please share your Routing syntax for "changeName " function?

Comment: _Resource_ routes only provide the basic CRUD actions - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers. You need to define a custom route.

Answer (score 1):

By the first image you posted I suppose you mean it doesn't appear on the routes, is that right? If so, it's because you need to define the route on the the `routes/web.php` file. For example like that :

```
Route::get('/changeName', 'ProductController@changeName');
```

Comment: so I need to set up Route::get('/changeName', 'ProductController@changeName'); right? Why I can't use resource instead of get?

Comment: ::resource will setup only the basic CRUD routes (the ones you see on your print), for other controller methods you are creating you have to define manually.

Comment: That's the best answer for me GMACHADO. Thank you so much. Are you a PHP amateur?

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @Java Script. And yeah, you could say that, I did some projects with PHP, especially with Laravel.